# How to solve this query issue?

Tags: sql

I am trying to complete a query to get the results that I really want but I am having some problems. This is the query that I am currently running:

```
SELECT Filetype AS 'Extensão', 
COUNT(*) AS 'Nº total de extensões',
((COUNT(Filetype) * 100.0) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM infofile)) AS 'Percentagem (%)',
SUM(Filesize) AS 'Total(KB)'
FROM infofile 
GROUP BY Filetype
UNION ALL
SELECT '---------------',
COUNT('Nº total de extensões'),
((COUNT(Filetype) * 100) / (SELECT COUNT(Filetype) FROM infofile)), 
SUM(Filesize)
FROM infofile
```

The Filetype column is nvarchar so I cant use AVG the way I want. The output of the query right now gives me the result of the total like 100.0000000000

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? There is some non-standard (invalid) SQL in your question.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: This is what I expect but I wanna get that 100.0000000... value without decimal

Comment: Have you tried casting the result?  ie: CAST(columname as numeric(9,2))

Comment: Assuming you're using an Oracle database you can use ROUND function to round the result: ROUND(((COUNT(Filetype) * 100) / (SELECT COUNT(Filetype) FROM infofile)), 0)

Answer (score 1):

If `FileType` is a number:

```
SELECT Filetype AS [Extensão], 
       COUNT(*) AS 'Nº total de extensões',
       COUNT(*) * 100.0)/SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS [Percentagem (%)],
       SUM(Filesize) AS [Total(KB)]
FROM infofile 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (Filetype), () );
```

I *think* this will do what you want.  You may need to calculate the percentage slightly differently for the final summary row.

Comment: @Rekcs, did you *try* the solution before commenting?

Answer (score 0):

The column type in the second part of your union must match that in the first part. Because in the first part you multiply by 100.0, your Percentage values will always have a decimal portion. This is why the last part is showing 100.00000 - even though if executed on it's own it would return an in.

If you want to keep it as a single union query, you could consider casting the Percentage values to nvarchar after performing the calculation. The floating point values in the first select would be kept as such while the integer result of the calculation in the second part should be converted directly to a string without being forced into floating point form.

Of course, if you want to use these values in numeric calculations later, this isn't really an option.